# Помогите разобраться как работают вложенные циклы

Tags: c#, консоль, for

Испытываю трудности с вложенными циклами, а когда дали дз нарисовать квадрат в консоли только благодаря циклу for, без помощи if else, то вообще потерялся. С обычными циклами, без вложений проблем нет.

Как работает второй цикл? Т.е внешний цикл выполняет условия какие либо, потом переходит к вложенному циклу, пока все итерации во вложенном не закончатся к внешнему программа не перейдет?

Comment: Что мешает запустить отладку шаг за шагом и посмотреть как и что делает ваша программа? Любой код, почти в любом языке читается сверху вниз, последовательно.

Comment: Это как скобки в арифметических выражениях: пока вы не выполните все то, что во вложенных скобках, вы не сможете перейти к выполнению расчетов далее, так и в циклах, если они вложены внутрь, пока они не пробегут свои значения, то уж точно вы не сможете перейти на первый цикл.

Comment: Если вопрос решён, вы можете принять ответ, для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы верно поняли. Как уже сказал EvgeniyZ код читается сверху вниз. Сделал для вас простой пример. В главном цикле у нас 5 итераций, а во вложенном их 3. Надеюсь он вам поможет.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Я - главный цикл и это {i} итерация из 5");
        for(int j = 1 ; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\tА я уже вложенный цикл. Это {j} итерация из 3");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

UPD:
Если захотите `взорвать` себе мозг, то можете попробовать написать/понять вычисление факториала через рекурсию)

Comment: Спасибо, хороший пример:) ❤️